# Butter Knife - Inject on Android lib

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, butterknife

I work on Android Studio with Gradle.

My issue is [Non-constant Fields in Case Labels](http://tools.android.com/tips/non-constant-fields).

When I use Butter Knife in Android lib, I get the following error:

```
tutuFragment.java:31: error: attribute value must be constant
    @InjectView(R.id.noContactTV)
```

Has anyone experienced the same issue, and if so, have a solution for it?

Answer (score 18):

According to https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife

> ### Library projects
>
> To use Butter Knife in a library, add the plugin to your buildscript:
>
> ```
> buildscript {
>   repositories {
>     mavenCentral()
>    }
>   dependencies {
>     classpath 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-gradle-plugin:8.4.0'
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> and then apply it in your module:
>
> ```
> apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
> apply plugin: 'com.jakewharton.butterknife'
> ```
>
> Now make sure you use R2 instead of R inside all Butter Knife
>   annotations.
>
> ```
> class ExampleActivity extends Activity {
>   @BindView(R2.id.user) EditText username;
>   @BindView(R2.id.pass) EditText password;
> ...
> }
> ```

So it's now to possible to use `Butterknife` injects in Android libs.

Hope it will help

Answer (score 11):

Butterknife does not support library projects at this time, please refer to https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/issues/100 for more informataion.

Answer (score 0):

Official github page has the solution: https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife

But when I obeyed the steps to config my library project, I went to some problems, 
such as NullPointerException, functions marked by @onClick annotition weren't invoked when the views were clicked, etc.

Then I changed somethings, and finally made it. Refer to this:  http://blog.csdn.net/ytzys/article/details/53243438

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced the same issue. I was getting this error whenever I wrote.

```
@BindView(R.id.pager) ViewPager pager;
```

or any other similar syntax for a view.

The reason for getting this error was that the R file that was imported into my java file was from the different package.

Now the question is why the R file imported was from a different package?

It was because I was using my project as a library into the other project. And while making the library I gave a different package name.